# Articles with food and structure "I have"

Tags: articles, zero-article

> I have **a** pineapple for lunch.
>
> I have pineapple for lunch.

Which version is correct?

What about these examples?

> I have soup for dinner.
>
> I have **a** soup for dinner.
>
> I have apple and chocolate bar for lunch.
>
> I have **an** apple and **a** chocolate bar for lunch.

Answer (score 2):

> I had a pineapple for lunch
>
> I had pineapple for lunch.

These are examples of the difference in English between measuring the *number* and the *amount* of various things.  **A** pineapple means *one, whole* pineapple -- a countable number.  **Pineapple** (without the article) means some *amount* of pineapple -- a bowl, a cup, a scoop, etc. -- in other words, some *uncountable* quantity.

So either "a pineapple" or just "pineapple" is fine, depending on what you *mean*.

Meanwhile, "soup" is *uncountable*, so you can't have "a soup".  Instead you would have instead some *amount* of soup for lunch -- a bowl, a cup, a liter, etc.

> I had soup for lunch
>
> I had a bowl of soup for lunch

Lastly, "apple" is like "pineapple" in that it can be either countable or uncountable.

> I had an apple for lunch
>
> If you put apple in your kale smoothie it tastes better.

"Chocolate" is uncountable, so if you want to specify a number you have to use some countable modifier -- "a bar", "a piece", "a cup".

> After lunch I shared a bar of chocolate with my coworker.

[More on countable and uncountable nouns](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/)

Comment: So it's just fine if I use "I have soup for lunch"?
What about these examples:
I have a chicken soup for lunch. or
I have chicken soup for lunch.

Comment: @user46036  based on the information I gave you, which do you think is correct?

Comment: "a" is often used when there is a standard serving or the serving is pre-packaged.  "I'll have a Coke" refers to whatever is the standard serving of Coke (bottle, can, cup).  "A soup" would refer to a standard serving of soup.

Comment: Let me protest on behalf of *a soup*. I've often had *a soup* for lunch. This description indicates that it's a particular soup, whether carrot, mushroom or pineapple (?), as opposed to just *soup*, which can be any old soup. The waiter might ask: *Would you like a soup?*

Comment: @fixer1234 Ronald Sole, while I agree that you can say "a soup", I think it's more the exception than the rule.  It's not something I personally would say, and I'm not sure it's a good thing to teach English learners who are trying to wrap their brains around the whole quantifiable / unquantifiable thing.  But it's not bad to add the caveat that it's something they might *hear*, even if they might avoid *using* it until they are more comfortable with the overall grammar.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure whether I stand reprimanded!

Comment: @ Andrew: I think that I have soup for lunch is correct because it's more general. But what if we add an adjective. I have a chicken soup for lunch. or I have chicken soup for lunch?

Comment: @user46036 - Even with an adjective, it sounds better to this native US English speaker not to use an article.  Yes, it is possible to say "**a** soup" if you absolutely need to specify one particular soup.  But if there isn't any need, it's much more common and fluent to treat *soup* as a mass noun and not use an article.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you're going to shovel in a whole pineapple or not.

I have a pineapple for lunch means you're going to eat a whole pineapple.

I have pineapple for lunch means you're going to eat some pineapple.

Comment: I have pineapple for lunch: Can it mean also to eat one whole pineapple? What about my other examples?

Comment: Yes, it's indeterminate about how much pineapple you eat.

Comment: You can't eat a soup because soup isn't quantal and it's had. It's quantity is determined by whatever contains it. Hence you could have a bowl of soup or a cup of soup but you can't have a soup.

Comment: A chocolate bar is quantal so you would have to say a chocolate bar or a bar of chocolate. Apple is the same as pineapple, an apple means a whole one, apple means some (an indeterminate amount).

Comment: I have an apple and a chocolate bar for lunch could be misread as a bar made of apple and a bar made of chocolate. I have an apple and a bar of chocolate would clarify that the apple was the fruit and not a confectionary.